# android how to change toolbar color when scroll by animation

Tags: android, animation, toolbar, background-color, android-nestedscrollview

I want change Toolbar color when scroll from white to red by animaion.
I tried to use alpha animation but it did not work well.
I dont know what should I do now.I want when nested scroll start scrolling the toolbar start changing color with animation
how can I do this?

Comment: Calculate toolbar position as percentage open/closed. Merge your two colors based on that percentage. Apply merged color to toolbar.

Comment: I can calculate the percentage of toolbar scrolling but how can I merge the colors?

Comment: Not sure. In an old project of mine I used a `ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)` to animate a color change. There has to be similar methods in other APIs. Normally, what you want to do in a situation like this is search Android's [API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference) for keywords related to your problem. Searching for "merge color" produces the `ColorUtils` class, which may be helpful in your situation.

Comment: the ColorUtils helped me,thank you

Comment: Nice! That's good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with this code:

```
if (scrollY > 0 && scrollY < 700) {
                            float alpha = (scrollY / 700f);
                            int resultColor = ColorUtils.blendARGB(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorWhite), ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), alpha);
                            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resultColor);
                            Log.i("LOG", "run: " + scrollY + "/" + odlScrollY);

                        } else if (scrollY < 50 && odlScrollY > scrollY) {
                            Log.i("LOG", "run: " + scrollY + "/" + odlScrollY);
                            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorWhite));
                        }
```